# Homogenous vs Heterogeneous Lists

Tags: java, java-8

Lets say I am designing a service called the ToyBox service which writes a bunch of shape objects to a database and returns the objects. The shapes it works with are polymorphic and therefore the structure is as below:

```
class Shape {
   int id;
}

class Circle extends Shape {
   int radius;
}

class Square extends Shape {
   int length;
}

class ToyBox {
   List<Shape> shapes;
}
```

Now my question is for the design of such a service, is it better for the ToyBox object to hold a reference to a collection of Shape objects or is it better for there to be a collection of each type of shape (ie. a `List<Square>, List<Circle>` etc) in a ShapeContainer? Same goes for the CRUD service interface, should it be accepting a List objects or a container object like so:

```
class ShapeContainer {
   List<Circle> circles;
   List<Square> squares;
}
```

A service method would be like such:

`List<ToyBox> persistToyboxes (List<ToyBox> boxes)`.

Elsewhere in the application, I would like to have different handling for squares vs circles so I would have to do the following if I went with the approach of ToyBox containing a `List<Shape>` objects:

```
List<Circle> circles = toyBox.getShapes().stream().filter(s -> s instanceOf Circle).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Just trying to decide what the best design is for such a system?

Comment: Seems like you need a more concrete idea on what you really want to do with these objects. This is far too abstract to say what the better approach is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is ... it depends.

Generally, it is simpler and cleaner (and the API is smaller) if the `ToyBox` API treats all shapes the same.  Treating them the same also means that you don't need to *change* the API to add (say) `Triangle` objects to the `ToyBox` API.

However, if there was something about the API requirements that mean that different shapes needed to be "contained" by the `ToyBox` in fundamentally different ways, then it *could* make sense for the `ToyBox` to have different API methods.

The implementation probably should reflect the API, but it doesn't absolutely have to.  For example, you could have separate API methods for the "collections" of circles, squares, etc, store them a single list object ... and implement the methods via some complicated filtering or wrapping.

The bottom line is this:  You need to understand the requirements that your API must meet ... and (ideally) reasonably anticipated *generalizations* of those requirements<sup>1</sup> ... and design accordingly.

---

<sup>1 - For example, a generalization of your `ToyBox` requirements that you should anticipate is that the user may want the API to be able to handle triangles.</sup>

---

By the way, this won't work:

```
List<Circle> circles = toyBox.getShapes().stream()
    .filter(s -> s instanceOf Circle)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The type of the `Stream` delivered by `filter` will be `Stream<Shape>`.  You would need to do something like this:

```
List<Circle> circles = toyBox.getShapes().stream()
    .filter(s -> s instanceOf Circle)
    .map(s -> (Circle) s)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

IMO, you are better off declaring a method in the `ToyBox` API like this:

```
public List<Circle> getCircles() { ... }
```

or even

```
public <T> List<T> getToysOfType(Class<T> typeClass) { ... }
```

Comment: I am leaning towards the approach of having the ToyBox contain a single list of Shapes. The only bad thing I can see with that is the need for casting all over the place if another part of my application only cares about one of the shapes (ie. lets say I have a webpage that only wants to display triangles). Generally I have been lead to believe that casting is a code smell but not sure how to treat it in this case?

Comment: There should be little / no need for casting if you are using polymorphism correctly.,

Comment: When I have List<Shape> shapes and want to perform an action on all Circular shapes, wouldnt my only option be to filter the list and cast the elements to Circle (after performing an instance of check)? I dont see another way that operation could work so can you comment on whether or not that is acceptable or suggest a different way to design a system that doesnt care about the type of Shapes when it comes to persisting to a DB but does care about type when doing any other actions

Comment: I guess its worth mentioning that this isnt a true polymorphic relationship since each subtype can have methods specific to only that subtype that my application would want to use. ie. the Circle object could have a method like getRadius() that could be called on circle objects and yet there would be no mention of this method in the base Shape class.

Comment: Another way to do that would be to implement this as an operations that is available for all shapes, an make it a no-op for non-circles.  A third way would be to have the `PlayBox` provide a `circleIterator()` method that delivers (only) the `Circle` objects in a playbox.  And so on.  There are lots ways to design your API to minimize class casts ... if that is a design goal.

Comment: On the other hand ... if your requirements are such that you have a lot of this kind of thing, then *design* it to support the requirements.  You **should not** design an API like this in a requirements-free vacuum.  And you shouldn't be asking for advice in an requirements-free vacuum either.

Comment: ok so going off your last answer, it seems like you are advising to go in the direction of having ToyBox hold an internal List<Shape> with convenience methods for getCircles() etc that filter the internal shapes list for the type required and returning a typed list of that particular shape. The service would deal with List<Shape> strictly to read and write any type of Shape objects. Do I have that right?

Comment: Yes .... that's what I am suggesting ... as one of the possible solutions.